# How to understand this use of Java generics

Tags: java, generics

In my study book, there's this example:

```
import java.util.*;
public class RentalGeneric<T> {

  private List<T> rentalPool;

  private int maxNum;
  public RentalGeneric(int maxNum, List<T> rentalPool) {

  this.maxNum = maxNum;
  this.rentalPool = rentalPool;
}
public T getRental() {
  return rentalPool.get(0);
}
  public void returnRental(T returnedThing) {
    rentalPool.add(returnedThing);
  }
}
```

I find it strange that it compiles, since there is no definition of `Class<T>`. What is the story about this? It says in my book that `T` is for the type parameter but how do I know when to use it?

Comment: You use it when you instantiate this class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use it to rent cars, bikes ...
You could use it directly like this:

```
RentalGeneric<Car> carRental = new RentalGeneric<Car>(10, aList);
```

Then when you'll do `getRental` it'll return you a `Car`object.
And you'll be able to put back a `Car` with `returnRental(aCar);`

Or you could create a `CarRental` class extending `RentalGeneric<Car>`.

Same thing goes for whatever object you would like to rent.

Answer (score 1):

T is generic Type here. It will be initialized while creating Object of `RentalGeneric` class.

```
RentalGeneric<Double> rgS =new RentalGeneric<Double>(10, new ArrayList<Double>());
RentalGeneric<Integer> rgS =new RentalGeneric<Integer>(10, new ArrayList<Integer>());
```

Answer (score 0):

You are right, there is no direct definition of `T` in your code. It is however can be found at runtime outside this code. Indeed somewhere you create instance of your list. When you do it you have to supply the type information, e.g.

`List<String> mylist = new ArrayList<String>();`

Here we defined that the list contains strings. Now we call your code:

`new RentalGeneric(123, mylist)`

`mylist` is a strings list, so `RentalGeneric`'s type parameter is `String` too.